# wincrypt output not matching other languages

Tags: c++, c, winapi, go, wincrypt

I've been attempting to play around with the wincrypt api, but can't seem to figure out why the output from CryptEncrypt doesn't match the output from a language like Go.

#### wincrypt code

```
BYTE *inBuffer = (BYTE*)"Hello World";
HCRYPTPROV phProv = NULL;
HCRYPTKEY key = NULL;
HCRYPTHASH hHash = NULL;
DWORD len = bufLen;

BYTE password[] = "password";
DWORD passLen = strlen((char*)password);

if (!CryptAcquireContext(&phProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)) {
    DWORD dwStatus = GetLastError();
    error.Fatal("CryptAcquireContext error %d", dwStatus);
}

if (!CryptCreateHash(phProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
    DWORD dwStatus = GetLastError();
    error.Fatal("CryptCreateHash error %d", dwStatus);
}

if (!hHash)
    error.Fatal("Hash create fail");

if (!CryptHashData(hHash, password, passLen, 0)) {
    DWORD dwStatus = GetLastError();
    error.Fatal("CryptHashData error %d", dwStatus);
}

if (!CryptDeriveKey(phProv, CALG_RC4, hHash, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &key)) {
    DWORD dwStatus = GetLastError();
    error.Fatal("CryptDeriveKey error %d", dwStatus);
}

if (!CryptEncrypt(key, 0, TRUE, 0, NULL, &len, 0)) {
    DWORD dwStatus = GetLastError();
    error.Fatal("CryptEncrypt error %d", dwStatus);
}

outBuffLen = len;
BYTE *cipherBlock = (BYTE*)calloc(len, sizeof(BYTE));
memcpy_s(cipherBlock, len, inBuffer, len);
if (!CryptEncrypt(key, 0, TRUE, 0, cipherBlock, &len, outBuffLen)) {
    DWORD dwStatus = GetLastError();
    error.Fatal("CryptEncrypt error %d", dwStatus);
}


CryptDestroyKey(key);
CryptReleaseContext(phProv, 0);
CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
```

#### go code

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rc4"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    key := []byte("5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99")
    src := []byte("Hello World")
    c, err := rc4.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    dst := make([]byte, len(src))
    c.XORKeyStream(dst, src)
    for _, x := range dst {
        fmt.Printf("%02X ", x)
    }
}
```

If the key is "password" the output should be: B7 90 54 62 23 1E E3 C1 13 3D CF

If the key is md5 hash of "password" ("5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99") the output should be: E4 F9 36 64 83 8A 3F 78 41 82 15

The output I'm getting from wincrypt: a0 9d 47 51 1a 7b 32 8e 03 54 c3

Is there something simple I'm missing?

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant. That said, this looks like C.

Comment: @tambre: `error.Fatal(...);` doesn't look much like C to me.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah, didn't notice that, in that case it might actually be C++. That said, the rest of the code is hardly C++ - using C-style booleans, using C-style null pointers, C-style casts, C strings, manual allocation/freeing, not using functions from the `std` namespace, what seem to be global enum values and probably more.

Comment: you must direct set size of rc4 key in call `CryptDeriveKey` - different ket size - different result. you can use equal key size in both methods for get the same result

Comment: Well the Windows code is calling CryptDeriveKey() to transform your input key into a stronger derived key, where are you doing that in your Go code?

Comment: @RbMm the default windows key length for rc4 looks to be 128 bits. However, changing the windows code and go code to "passwordpassword" still doesn't make them match.

Comment: default key length depend from used provider and possible windows version

Comment: Completely understand, but using 0x00800000 for 128 bit key and 0x00500000 for 40 bit key neither return a matching result.